# Pie Chart using SVG

Tags: html, css, svg, geometry

I want to create a pie chart that indicates progress 8/8 as whole and 4/8 as half. I already manage to create one but it seems that it started on the 90 degrees angle. i want it to start from 0 degrees. I dont want to use rotation because it has a **Text** inside

this is what i have so far

```css
.pie-assign {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.pie-assign circle {
  fill: yellow;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 30;
}

.circle-0 { stroke-dasharray: 0 100; }
.circle-1 { stroke-dasharray: 12.5 150; }
.circle-2 { stroke-dasharray: 25 100; }
.circle-3 { stroke-dasharray: 37.5 100; }
.circle-4 { stroke-dasharray: 50 100; }
.circle-5 { stroke-dasharray: 62.5 100; }
.circle-6 { stroke-dasharray: 75 100; }
.circle-7 { stroke-dasharray: 87.5 100; }
.circle-8 { stroke-dasharray: 105 100; }
```

```html
<div style="width:100px; height: 100px;">
<svg class="pie-assign" viewBox="0 0 30 30">
  <circle class="circle-1" r="15" cx="15" cy="15" />
  <text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" fill="gray" dy=".3em">A</text>
</svg>
</div>
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use rotation without rotating your text content.

For example you can apply it to a `<circle>` element:

```
<circle r="15" cx="15" cy="15" transform="rotate(45,15,15)" />
```

The first value is the rotation in degrees. Second and third value are the coordinates of the rotation center.

Comment: i dont know why but my circle doesn't look like a perfect circle when i apply that https://jsfiddle.net/hu0rvoLh/3/ thanks btw

Comment: Ah, the rotation center was missing. I've updated the answer.